# Is there a way to validate phone number globally inLaravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have validated UAE-based phone numbers in Laravel. Is there any way to validate all countries numbers (not only UAE-based)?

```php
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'integer' => 'The :attribute field value should be an integer.',
    'regex' => 'The :attribute is invalid',
    'digits' => 'The :attribute is invalid',
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
        'number' => 'required|digits:12|regex:/(9715)[0-9]{8}/',
        'service' => 'required|integer'
    ],
    $messages
);
```

Comment: Generally this is discouraged. Your task is to capture a phone number in the way the user wishes to provide it, with spaces, hyphens and brackets as they normally write it themselves. It is already hard to persuade people to part with their phone numbers, so if you make it hard for them, they will either choose to not share it, or they will put in nonsense in order to prevent you having it. If you make it really difficult, you will lose them as a customer. Just accept a string.

Comment: Actually you can do with this package https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone. I am using it. Depends on your requirement.

Comment: What I usually do is to validate with the package `propaganistas/laravel-phone` in the back, use `libphonenumber-js` in the front to help the users filling their number. But when the phone is not used in a service, I let them fill whatever they want. You could validate there isn't "a-zA-Z" characters though. But I believe that **restrictive** validation is not a good thing on that. If a user want to fill a wrong number, he will do it anyway.